# Animal Detection dataset

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, computer-vision

Update 1:
I know that I can seperate animal,bird object annotations/images from imagenet. In fact I already filtered annotations/images that are my interested and downloaded them by URL. I searched for another dataset for the following reasons.

I have roughly around 30K animal 30K bird objects. I included children synsets of animal synset as animal and children synsets of bird synset as bird. However, after training 100K iteration, YOLO object detector gives me only 45mAP which is not desirable.

The reason for this low performance is has to do with imagenet annotations: 
Image that belongs animal category only annotated animals and takes people as background. However, my dataset contains annotation of people in other images. Hence, this conflict is making hard for detector to learn.

[image: imagenet annotation of animal(horse)]

Now I am considering COCO dataset.

**Original Question:**

I need to train a model that detects following objects:

- People
- Animal
- Bird

I already have enough images and annotations for people. 
Could anybody kindly suggest a dataset for that purpose which contains any class of animal or bird?

Comment: Have you looked through ImageNet? It has categories which you can search, so should be possible to sample it for "animal", "bird" etc by selecting relevant categories. Definitely plenty of images.

Comment: hi @NeilSlater, in fact I did. I updated my question about it.

Comment: It may be quicker to do a manual filter of ImageNet for your purpose than to search for an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

[ImageNet](http://www.image-net.org/) is the gold standard for labeled image training data. It contains both ["animal"](http://www.image-net.org/search?q=animal) and ["bird"](http://www.image-net.org/search?q=bird) categories.

Comment: thanks for the answer @brian, but unfortunately, for the above reasons in my updated question, imagenet didn't suffice me even when I downloaded all the children synsets of animal and bird.